# How to reorient single character images properly with opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, tesseract, python-tesseract

How to orient these images of letters taken from a drone properly. I've tried the fitellipse function in opencv, but it sometimes fits the ellipse in the worng way, leading to rotate the letter the wrong way.

[the ellipse fits it  horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhrQk.png)

[Another example which when rotated wont give the proper letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4e93.png)

[letter 'D' after orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk58k.png)
[letter 'U' after orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDe23.png)

cv2.fitellipse gives the angle the major axis of the ellipse makes with the y-axis (anti-clockwise direction). I'm rotating the image anti-clockwise by 180-angle, to re-orient it, i.e. make the ellipse vertical/parallel to y-axis.

I'm doing all this because tesseract ocr is not properly recognising disoriented letters like these even in its "psm 10" mode, meant for single character recognition.
Any suggestions on how to reorient these letters, or how to make tesseract work with disoriented letters will greatly help!

Comment: your rotation result for U doesn't look right. the ellipse looks horizontal to me but the corrected U is rotated quite a bit. you could simply rotate the letter until it is recognized as it will be difficult too impossible to get the orientation of all characters without identifying them. how would you get @'s orientation through your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work without some domain knowledge as to what you are looking for. You cannot simply assume that whatever letter you take, ellipse fitting will give you the answer - what about symmetrical letters? What about the perspective that can make the letter appear flattened? You could even use FFT or PCA to get principal axis out of the pixels creating the letter and estimate its rotation, however it won't be much better than the ellipse fitting for the same reasons.

One possible solution would be rotation and scale invariant pattern matching, where you'd try to find all the possible letters in the image, but it might give you some false positives and working only for a single (or similar) font family. I'd go towards machine-learning based approaches if it fails, such as SVM.